# can console application create window on its own?

Tags: c++, winapi

Let's say I have pure command line application, but I want add a way for showing some of the info in a pop up window that will be created when user press a key. So the window won't be visible from the start, but only as an option for the user. What function use to achieve that - `CreateWindowEx` ? Is there any working example that I can compile in MinGW ?

Comment: It doesn't take anything special.  Find out more by reading Petzold's "Programming Windows".

Answer (score 1):

A console app is a normal Win32/64 process like any other, it just uses a different UI model by default.  It has full access to the entire Win32 API, so there is nothing preventing a console app from displaying GUI windows if it wants to.